# Split Array into Two Arrays Based on Criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have a sheet of data with many columns on it. We'll call this Sheet1 One of these columns has a unique ID.

[image]

I have another sheet with data. We'll call this Sheet2.

[image]

**The Ask:**
If all of the contents of Sheet1 are in one array and the contents of column A from Sheet2 are in another array, I want to be able to derive those rows from Sheet1 that match and put it on Sheet3 and those that do not match unto Sheet4. I want to be able to call this in a function so the input variables should be `sheet1Arr`, `sheet1ColNum` (Column to be matched with) and `sheet2ColArr`. I'd like the output to be two arrays. `outputWCriteriaArr` and `outputWOCriteriaArr`. If it makes things easier the output can be pasted directly into the sheets within the function. We'll just need two more input variables, `outputWCriteriaSht` and `outputWOCriteriaSht`.

Using the images above, Sheet3 should look like this:

[image]

And Sheet4 should look like this:

[image]

Other info:

- Number of rows for Sheet1 can be in excess of 10K. Has been as high as 33K and there may be cases where it will be a lot more.

Here is my attempt so far.

```
function splitArrayBasedonCriteria(dataArray,criteriaArray,dataColToMatch,outputWCriteriaSht,outputWOCriteriaSht){
  //criteriaArray should be one column
  var outputWCriteriaArr = [];
  var outputWOCriteriaArr = [];

  //Search for strings in specific column and store in array
  for (var j in criteriaArray) {
    for (var i in dataArray){
      //Logger.log(dataArray[i][dataColToMatch - 1])
      if (dataArray[i][dataColToMatch - 1].toString().indexOf(criteriaArray[j].toString()) == -1) { 
        outputWOCriteriaArr.push(dataArray[i])
      } else {
        outputWCriteriaArr.push(dataArray[i])
      }
    }
  }


  Logger.log(outputWCriteriaArr);
  Logger.log(outputWOCriteriaArr);
  //Output array that met criteria
  var destRange = outputWCriteriaSht.getRange(1,1,outputWCriteriaArr.length, outputWCriteriaArr[0].length)
  destRange.setNumberFormat("@"); //format cells before pasting values to keep leading zeros.
  destRange.setValues(outputWCriteriaArr)
  //Output array that did not meet criteria
  var destRange = outputWOCriteriaSht.getRange(1,1,outputWOCriteriaArr.length, outputWOCriteriaArr[0].length)
  destRange.setNumberFormat("@"); //format cells before pasting values to keep leading zeros.
  destRange.setValues(outputWOCriteriaArr)
}
```

I was attempting to use indexOf to find data in that particular column but I don't think `dataArray[i][dataColToMatch - 1].toString().indexOf(criteriaArray[j].toString()) == -1` is the proper way to do that. I know the variables are named differently on this function. Either way is ok. I thought the variables in my explanation made more sense for the purpose of this write-up.

Comment: Hello @DanCue, what did you try in order to accomplish your task? Do you have any code snippets available? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 Just added my attempt.

Comment: I'm thinking about using an array of just the column I'm looking at. Use 'indexOf()' on that but push the row from the other array into the new array. I think that will work except I don't think `indexOf()` works with the data in question because its numeric. Even though it's formatted as plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Flow:

- Create a `Set` using unique values from second array `arr2`.
- If  first array's `arr1` unique Id matches anything from set,
- swap it to the end of the array
- else, move on to the next item.
- By this, matched rows are moved to the end of the array and unmatched rows are kept at the top

#### Sample script:

```js
/**
 * @param {object[][]} arr1
 * @param {object[][]} arr2
 * @param {number} arr1Index Index of arr1 containing unique id
 * @param {number} arr2Index Index of arr2 containing unique id
 */
function splitZArr(arr1, arr2, arr1Index, arr2Index) {
  const arr2Set = new Set(arr2.map(row => row[arr2Index]));
  let end = arr1.length - 1;

  for (let start = 0; start <= end; ) {
    const uid = arr1[start][arr1Index];
    if (arr2Set.has(uid)) {
      [arr1[end], arr1[start]] = [arr1[start], arr1[end]];
      --end;
    } else {
      ++start;
    }
  }
  return { matched: arr1.splice(++end), unmatched: arr1 };
}

(function test() {
  console.info(
    splitZArr(
      [
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 4],
      ],
      [[2], [4]],
      1,
      0
    )
  );
})();
```

Comment: This outputs both arrays instead of pasting it to the sheet within the function. Good, as long as I can call on each array individually once I've exited the function. Can you add directions on how to access those arrays?

Comment: @Dan Come on... At least try to figure it out.

Comment: @Dan No one is going to stumble on this.  Even If they did, they should ask a new question "How to retrieve array from objects?" or "How to use setValues?" or read basics and take up tutorials. In any case, it is unrelated to the question "Split array into two arrays based on criteria".

Comment: One issue with this though is that it is not matching on any. They are all going to unmatched. I think it has something to do with the formatting of the Unique IDs. They have leading zeros and were formatted as plain text.

Comment: @Dan convert it to  the same type in sheet? or script: `row => Number(row[arr2Index])` and `uid = Number(arr1[start][arr1Index])`?

Comment: I've tried both converting to same type in the sheet and using that code within the script. It is still not pushing any values to the matching array.

Comment: @Dan Better to ask a new question with a demonstrable/runnable snippet (like my answer) with sample arr1 and arr2 values.

Comment: I figured it out. My fault. The columns should be zero-indexed. I can confirm this works. It's also very fast. Thank you, @TheMaster

Comment: @Dan  Great. Next time you ask a question, simulate sheet values and provide a runnable snippet. Cheers.